# Is my app in /system?

Tags: android, system

My application can be installed and run on android,
in two different places:

```
"/data/MyApplication"
```

and

```
"/system/MyApplication".
```

I need to know where at the moment is my application installed,
if it is in "/data/" or if it is in "/system".

Can anyone help?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adb to find out:

$ adb shell ls /data

or

$ adb shell ls /system

Or do you want this check at runtime from within your application. In that case you could use

System.getProperty("user.dir")

in your Java code.

Comment: I really need to know this at runtime

Comment: Ok, added that to my answer. Hope this helps.

Comment: With "System.getProperty("user.dir")" I only get this: "/". ;-(

Comment: Hm, wrong property maybe. Google for getProperty and Android might give you the answer. Will check this myself as well.

Answer (score 3):

Obtain where your application is installed by

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), 0).sourceDir
```

however this should not be important for your application.
Why do you need it ?

Comment: I need to know where my app is installed. And yes, it will be installed as a system application but also OTA and I need to know where it is. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Please don't hard-code checks to directory paths.

You can find out of your app is part of the built-in system image with ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM.  But as the other poster says, there should be few reasons to need to do this...  and note that if a newer version of your app is installed from Market on a device that has it bundled, FLAG_SYSTEM will still be set since it is still effectively a system app.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below hard code to found the location of user installed application path either in /data or /system:

```
PackageInfo paramPackageInfo = null;
        try {
            paramPackageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

ApplicationInfo localApplicationInfo = paramPackageInfo.applicationInfo;
```

To found package name : `localApplicationInfo.packageName`

To found application path : `localApplicationInfo.sourceDir`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use package manager tool for that. **adb shell pm path your.package.name**

Sample of usage:

```
#List all installed packages
$ adb shell pm list packages
package:com.android.soundrecorder
....
package:com.android.email           # <-- System app
....
package:course.labs.intentslab.test # <-- Custom app

#Path for system app:
$ adb shell pm path com.android.email
package:/system/app/Email.apk

#Path for regular app:
$ adb shell pm path course.labs.intentslab.test
package:/data/app/course.labs.intentslab.test-1.apk
```

From documentation:

**path  PACKAGE Print the path to the APK of the given PACKAGE**

[Using package manager (pm)](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm)

[Some info on Android StackOverflow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11052/what-useful-android-shell-commands-do-you-know)